# How do I change call forward number?

Tags: settings

I have two phones, one from work and one of my own. Outside office hours I still want to get calls from customers or colleagues, so I use call forwarding feature a lot. The Windows Phone remembers which number I usually forward to, and that’s great. But I’m curious of how I should do to change it, if I need to.

[image: Nokia Lumia call forwarding]

**Q:** How do I change call forward number?

Comment: The blur you used is practically useless :D

Comment: Then call me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you've got the number in a box, that's actually a button, and pressing it will prompt you to choose a different destination to divert to.

Answer (score 2):

In my Sansung Focus when I turn it off and after turn it on again it asks again for the number.

In the state you show I can click on the phone number and change.

Another trick that works (in Brazil works) is activate forward by calling to *21*phoneNumber# and to desactivate call #21#

Comment: Good answer (+1). On my network in Canada, #21# often ends up getting tangled in the phone company's HLR.  A complete reset of the call forwarding can help avoid this (I use `##21#`.)  I have contacts for my most common "forward to X" and "unforward" numbers.  This makes it easy to do without typing numbers all the time.  See http://www.geckobeach.com/cellular/secrets/gsmcodes.php for a pretty comprehensive list of GSM feature codes.